# What could be causing low hot water pressure to a sink?

Tags: water

I have low hot water pressure at the kitchen sink.  I installed a new two knob faucet and supply lines (aerator is clean), but no change. The shut off valve has a PEX fitting, so I don't know how to replace that. The hot water pressure to the sinks and showers in two bathroom is fine.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect the hot feed from the faucet and purge it into a bucket. Then, (re-attach it and disconnect it from the valve) put the bucket under the sink (to catch the flow from the loose line) and run the faucet in the middle (or both hot and cold).

This will purge the hot side of the facet, backwards (and make a mess if you're not careful), in case there's crud in the tap now, too. Open and close ALL valves repeatedly to clear them while you purge.

Comment: "Disconnect the hot feed.... Then, put the bucket under the sink."  Where is the hot feed?  Isn't it under the sink?

Answer (score 0):

I'll set myself up for some downvotes here, but I hate these things. It's a Water"sense" faucet. When low-flow just isn't enough for the smallest bill in the house get no-sense & get a Watersense faucet! Now available in almost dribble! Take filling pots & pitchers to a whole new level of not awesome!